# Nothing happens when I run the scheduler in java

Tags: java

I'm creating a scheduler which is doing reminder every monday. I wrote this codes but when I run it with Tomcat Server, there isn't any response in eclipse's console.

**runWeekly.java**

```
package Listener;

public class runWeekly {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new WeeklyReportService();
    }

}
```

**WeeklyReportService.java**

```
package Listener;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WeeklyReportService {
    public WeeklyReportService(){
        this.startScheduler();
    }

    private void startScheduler(){
        Calendar with = Calendar.getInstance();
        Map<Integer, Integer> dayToDelay = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.FRIDAY, 2);
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.SATURDAY, 1);
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.SUNDAY, 0);
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.MONDAY, 6);
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.TUESDAY, 5);
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, 4);
                dayToDelay.put(Calendar.THURSDAY, 3);
                int dayOfWeek = with.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                int hour = with.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int delayInDays = dayToDelay.get(dayOfWeek);
                int delayInHours = 0;
                if(delayInDays == 6 && hour<12){
                    delayInHours = 12 - hour;
                }else{
                    delayInHours = delayInDays*24+((24-hour)+12);
                }
         ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);            
         scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new WeeklyTask(), delayInHours,
                                       179, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```

**WeeklyTask.java**

```
package Listener;

public class WeeklyTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm running every monday at 12 pm");
    }
}
```

It has to write that **I'm running every monday at 12 pm** in eclipse's console but it's not writing.
I tried to run it like java application but it didn't work too.

Comment: What is the value of `delayInHours`? It is the initial delay the program should wait before executing the scheduler for the first time. Also, your time unit is HOURS so you should wait `delayInHours` hours. Also, don't call `startSchedule()` in the constructor! Make it a public method and call it from `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialDelay is too big.

Lets count for thursday 12pm:

```
delayInHours = 3*24+((24-12)+12)=96
```

So it will start in 96 hours

Comment: I've changed it to **91** for thurdays 17 pm but there is nothing in eclipse's console.

Comment: When you set start schedule second param (your `delayInHours`)  says schedule to firstly start after this delay. 
_initialDelay - the time to delay first execution_. So your shedule will firstly run in 91 days after program start. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: @demir5334 I recommend you to change the approach: run scheduler every hour like this: `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new WeeklyTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);` and in your task check if current time is what you want. If you really need to run the scheduled task based on day/time, use Quarz and cron-like approach. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/

Comment: @phil_g I need to run it every monday to do this I think I need to change `TimeUnit.HOURS` to `TimeUnit.DAYS`. Am I right?